# Passing arrays to functions in c++ code error

Tags: c++

I am learning C++, and I cannot figure out why this code outputs the right number of outputs (4), but only output the number 54. Can someone help fix it and explain what I did wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void pi(int arr[],int x){
    for(int c = 0;c < x;c++){
        cout << arr[x] << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int _arr[4] = {3543,146,961262,-242};
    pi(_arr, 4);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing the array limit with the indexer. Should be:

```
 cout << arr[c] << endl;
```

Arrays are zero indexed. You are trying to print out the element that is out of bounds thus invoking undefined behaviour. Depending on the platform your output might look like four `0` or something like `-858993460`. By convention counter variables usually start with the letter `i`.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is weird. It could make the computer dance the Hokey-Pokey and call Dominoes to order a pizza, though I admit spitting out a garbage number is more likely.

Answer (score 3):

Since `x` is 4, `arr[x]` is `arr[4]`. But `_arr` only has four entries, it doesn't have a fifth entry. So you are outputting garbage. You probably meant `arr[c]` in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
cout << arr[x] << endl;
```

To

```
cout << arr[c] << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the loop inside the function

```
for(int c = 0;c < x;c++){
    cout << arr[x] << endl;
               ^^^
}
```

There should be

```
for(int c = 0;c < x;c++){
    cout << arr[c] << endl;
               ^^^
}
```

It is the variable `c` that serves as an index in the array.

Nevertheless the program has several drawbacks.

You should not use identifiers starting with an underscore. Such names can be reserved by the compiler implementation.

Do not use "magic numbers". They are usually serve as a reason for bugs.

To store sizes of objects or arrays use the type `size_t` instead of the type `int`.

The function does not change the array. So the corresponding parameter should be declared with the qualifier `const`.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>

void pi( const int arr[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 3543, 146, 961262,-242 };
    pi( arr, sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr ) );
}
```

Take into account that you could output the array using a standard algorithm as for example `std::for_each` or `std::copy`.

Here is a demonstrative program that uses the standard algorithm `std::copy` to output the array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 3543, 146, 961262,-242 };
    std::copy( std::begin( arr ), 
               std::end( arr ), 
               std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, "\n" ) );
}
```